# taskdef class PackageName.ClassName cannot be found

Tags: java, ant, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm trying to run Selenium tests that are build with Java + Selenium + TestNG + Ant. But, when I run `build.xml` following error is thrown -

```
BUILD FAILED
G:\Workspace\AntProject\build.xml:14: taskdef class AntPackage.AntTest cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[G:\Workspace\AntProject\libs\testng-6.8.jar]

Total time: 645 milliseconds
```

Following is `build.xml` -

```
<project basedir="." default="runTest" name="Ant file for TestNG">

<property name="src" location="src"/>
<property name="bin" location="bin"/>
<property name="libs" location="libs"/>

<path id="class.path">
    <pathelement location="${libs}/testng-6.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${libs}/selenium-java-2.40.0-srcs.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${libs}/selenium-java-2.40.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${libs}"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="test" classname="AntPackage.AntTest">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="libs/testng-6.8.jar"/>
        </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="runTest">
    <mkdir dir="testng_output"/>
    <testng outputdir="testng_output" classpathref="class.path">
        <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/>
    </testng>
</target>
</project>
```

and following is `testng.xml` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="AntPackage.AntTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The class `AntTest` is under `AntPackage`.

I made changes in `build.xml` as per answer of [The taskdef ant task cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831194/the-taskdef-ant-task-cannot-be-found) but it still didn't work.

Comment: can you try <class name="**/AntTest.class"> and make sure this class is in your classpath you have mentioned in the ant classpath element.

Answer (score 4):

Do not specify `classname="AntPackage.AntTest"` but add taskdef as per documentation `<taskdef resource="testngtasks"   classpath="${libs.dir}/testng-6.8.jar" />` http://testng.org/doc/ant.html

```
`<taskdef />`  is needed to specify path to testng.jar but not your test classes
```

Comment: Package name is simply `AntPackage`

Comment: Wait, AntPackage.AntTest -- is the class with tests you want to run?

Comment: But you should look for AntTest under `${bin}`

Answer (score 1):

In build.xml, replace...

```
<taskdef name="test" classname="AntPackage.AntTest">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="libs/testng-6.8.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

...with...

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${libs}/testng-6.8.jar"/>
```